# Google chart group by seconds

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, jsfiddle

For simplicity I made this chart for question [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q5vc8gc1/4/).
Can I group this bars by seconds or minutes or hours?
New grouped bar should have value 2 but not 1 i.e. grouped bars it is sum
Code in jsfiddle:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('timeofday', 'Time of Day');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Emails Received');

  data.addRows([
    [[8,30,30],1],
    [[8,30,30],1],
    [[8,30,31],1],
    [[8,30,31],1],
    [[8,30,32],1],
    [[8,30,32],1],
    [[8,30,33],1],
    [[8,30,33],1],
    [[8,30,34],1],
    [[8,30,34],1],
  ]);

  var options = google.charts.Bar.convertOptions({
    title: 'Total Emails Received Throughout the Day',
    height: 450
  });

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: are you referring to `isStacked` vs. _grouped_? the chart above appears to be grouped by seconds...

Comment: @WhiteHat Yes I mean I need to stack data on the same seconds or all data in one minute or one hour. But unlike 'isStacked' my data has one column..

Comment: only way i know to stack would be to add columns -- `[[8,30,30],1,1]` vs. `[[8,30,30],1],[[8,30,30],1]`

Comment: @WhiteHat For example in highstock product "Data Grouping" - group data by pixels and stack points, so google can't do this ? Unfortunately this way doesn't suit me.

Comment: not sure i follow exactly but google charts relies heavily on a specific [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#data-format). you have to manipulate the data, in order to produce the chart you need. is there an example image of the chart you want?

Comment: @WhiteHat Actually here is right result https://jsfiddle.net/q5vc8gc1/17/ . You can see bars on the same seconds is stacked and equal 2.